# Add message on product page

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, global-messages

I want to add a warning message on the product page but it's not working if full page cache is enabled.
I'm using the following event

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view">
        <observer name="product_view_custom_action" instance="My\Module\Observer\Custom"/>
</event>
```

And in observer execute I have the following

```
$this->messageManager->addWarningMessage(__('My warning message'));
```

Is there a method that I could do this to show the warning message every time. Even after the page is cached?

Comment: We can use Ajax.

Comment: Hi @KhoaTruongDinh, could you point me to an example? Thank you.

Comment: @Magarusu Did you able to solve this ?

Comment: @Vinoth Yes, I forgot to update the question. I've added my solution, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve this using a template defined under:
My/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="My\Module\Block\Messages" name="CUSTOM_ID" as="CUSTOM_ID"
               template="My_Module::messages.phtml" after="messages"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

And then in your phtml file:

```
<div role="alert" class="messages">
    <div class="message-warning warning message">
        <div><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('My warning message')) ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use magento event http_response_send_before.

Comment: 'http_response_send_before' does not work and I can't seem to find this dispatch in the code.
I've tried a plugin on 'Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http::beforeSendResponse' and it does not work either. The code is called every time but only when I hit an uncached page will the message be show. And it's shown for every time it got triggered. Meaning, if I refresh a cached page severl times, when I hit an uncached one it will show my message for each previous hit.